# Dynamic body in html for making wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Can you help me, please ? Maybe this question is stupid but I am new in Wordpress. First I have created project using html and css, javascript. Then, I have converted my html code to wordpress theme. For example I have written get_header() instead of html head and get_footer() instead of html footer. Finally I must do dynamic my project's body but I can't. For example when i change page, header and footer must stay in its place but body must changing. Problem is I do not know to write code in my body section. [my code's seem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rNOt.png)

I have called my other section though get_template_part().
I have tried to write my html code in adding wordpress page, to be more clear, in wordpress dashboard. When I change page, body's seem must changing.

What should i do, please ?

Comment: Can you confirm that all of those files exist in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

In your templates add the HTML of particular pages like the home page and other cms pages and in the admin dashboard go to the Pages section in the page template and assign the particular page template for example you have created a home page template for the main page go to pages in admin dashboard in page template assign the home page to the page then you can see the HTML of the page on frontend.